# Cannot run mysql syntax on select

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

I tried running this in phpmyadmin...
It turned out something is not right.
I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

```
DELIMITER ;
create definer=proiect_wd_user@localhost FUNCTION
f_suma(id_s int, price_f double,product_code_n char(255),quantity_b int)
returns double
BEGIN
select price_f into @price_f
from orders_details WHERE (id=id_s)
select quantity_b into @quantity_b
from orders_details WHERE (id=id_s)
set @suma_f=(@price_f*@quantity_b);
RETURN @suma_f;
end ;

Error:

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select quantity_b into @quantity_b
from orders_details WHERE (id=id_s)
set @su' at line 7
```

Comment: every statement needs a terminator.

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems here with your delimiters. See [Working with Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) in the MySQL documentation.

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_suma;

DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=proiect_wd_user@localhost 
FUNCTION f_suma(id_s int,price_f double,product_code_n char(255),quantity_b int) 
RETURNS double
BEGIN
SELECT price_f INTO @price_f FROM orders_details WHERE (id=id_s);
SELECT quantity_b INTO @quantity_b FROM orders_details WHERE (id=id_s);
SET @suma_f=(@price_f*@quantity_b);
RETURN @suma_f;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to recreate what you did in another function but it did not work. I cannot understand what I did wrong.  `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_data;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=proiect_wd_user@localhost 
FUNCTION f_data(code_n char(5),Data_prod date) 
RETURNS date;
BEGIN
SELECT Data_prod  INTO @Data_prod FROM movies WHERE (code_n=code);
SET @data_f=((YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(@Data_prod));
RETURN @data_f;
END //`

Comment: @Cloof101 The `;` needs removing after `RETURNS date`. You also have mismatched parentheses and don't need them all. Use `SET @data_f=YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(@Data_prod);`. These are basic mistakes. Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.